# Message collector responds to other people's messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make a collector which will collect the mentioned user's message. But even with filter my bot respond to it's own message and other peoples messages! Here is my `test.js` file code:

```js
const mentioned = message.mentions.users.first();

const filter1 = (msg) => {
  return msg.author.id === mentioned.id
}

const collector1 = await message.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter1, max: 1, time: 120000 })

collector1.on('collect', message => {
  console.log(message.content)
})

collector1.on('end', (collected) => {
  if (collected.size === 0) return message.channel.send("Mentioned user did not respond in time!")

  collected.forEach((message) => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == 'accept') {
      message.channel.send(`${mentioned} accepted!`)
    }
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == 'cancel') return message.channel.send(`${mentioned} declined!`)
  })
})
```

I was changing my filter many times, but I still can't fix this problem, so what am I doing wrong?
Also I use djs v13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to use [Short-Hand Property Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) to assign the `filter` option. However, you pass in "`filter1`" which results in `{filter1: filter1}`. Since this does not resolve to a `filter` option for [TextChannel#createMessageCollector()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector) the method disregards the unknown option and therefor your collector has no filter.

Change your `filter1` variable to `filter`

```js
const filter = (msg) => {
  return msg.author.id === mentioned.id
}

const collector1 = await message.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter, max: 1, time: 120000 })
```

Comment: But what if I have more than one collector in my command and I need different filters for both

Comment: `{filter: filterN}`, short hand assignment is optional